# Why Python format function is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

In python I wrote:

```
list_of_assets = []
list_of_assets.append(('A', 'B', 'C'))
for asset in list_of_assets:
    print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format([asset[0], asset[1], asset[2]]))
```

But I get:

```
print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format([asset[0], asset[1], asset[2]]))
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the `format` parameters in a list:

```
list_of_assets = []
list_of_assets.append(('A', 'B', 'C'))
for asset in list_of_assets:
    #                              here  ↓                  and here ↓
    print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format(asset[0], asset[1], asset[2]))
```

output:

```
A                 B                                C
```

Even better, you could use parameter expansion:

```
for asset in list_of_assets:
    print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format(*asset))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error came because you passed a list argument to the format function. Pass individual elements of the list instead.

Your code should be like this:

```
list_of_assets = []
list_of_assets.append(('A', 'B', 'C'))
for asset in list_of_assets:
    print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format(asset[0], asset[1], asset[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
list_of_assets = []
list_of_assets.append(('A', 'B', 'C'))
for asset in list_of_assets:
    print('{:15}   {:30}   {:30}'.format(asset[0],asset[1],asset[2]))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.